# How to set a default icon in menu bar according to the server response in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am having list of colleges. If I click one of the college it has go to detail page which has a `menu bar` with `favourite_icon`.If I click the `favourite_icon` that college is stored as favourite in server and that `favourite_icon` changed as `favourite_icon1`.If we chech the college detail again after some times that menu bar `favourite_icon` should be `favourite_icon1` if that college is already favoiurited.I am having the API to check whether the college is favourited or not if it favourited the response is like `"status=fav"` otherwise `"status=not_fav"`.

Here I have added the code for your reference

menu_clg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appmunu="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".UserDashBoardFragment">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_notify"
        android:icon="@drawable/mail_icon"
        appmunu:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Notification" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favourite"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_selector"
        appmunu:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Favourite" />


</menu>
```

icon_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/vijay"

        />

    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/favourite_icon"
        />
</selector>
```

activity code

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_clg, menu);
        mMenu = menu;


        return true;
    }

    // delete the selected event from event list added here
    boolean canAddItem = false;
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_notify:
                navigatetoNotification();
                return true;



            case R.id.action_favourite:
                if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_favourite){
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    favouriteClg();
                }



        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        if(canAddItem){
            menu.getItem(1).setIcon(R.drawable.vijay);
            canAddItem = false;
            favouriteClg();
        }
        else{
            menu.getItem(1).setIcon(R.drawable.favourite_icon);
            canAddItem = true;
            favouriteClg();
        }

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

favourtieclg() method

```
 public void favouriteClg() {

        final CollegeMO collegeMO = (CollegeMO) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("CollegeMO");
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        userMO = db.getUserData(1);
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                return favouriteDelegates.addFavourite(userMO, collegeMO, context);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String userData) {
                if (!userData.equals("0") && null != userData) {
                    UserMO userMO = gson.fromJson(userData, new TypeToken<UserMO>() {
                    }.getType());

                    if (userMO.getStatus().equals("success")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), userMO.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i achieved it, hope this help. You can also use `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` or `InvalidateOptionsMenu()` to update changes.

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear(); //If you want to clear the menu
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
        updateMenuIcon(menu);
    }

    private void updateMenuIcon(Menu menu) {
        if (menu == null) return;
        if (condition) {//Check for some condition
            changeMenuIcon(menu, R.drawable.fav);
        } else {
            changeMenuIcon(menu, R.drawable.not_fav);
        }
    }

    private void changeMenuIcon(Menu menu, int resource) {
        Drawable newIcon = getResources().getDrawable(resource);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_fav).setIcon(newIcon);
    }
```